# Finding an undefined with first string in the array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing the following:

```
<p>1983 (on television), 1984 (in theatres)</p>
```

The I run

```
var d;
var dateText = $("p").text().split(/\s+/g);
for(var i = 0; i < dateText.length; i++) {
  d += dateText[i] + ' ';
}
var words = d.replace("–", " ").replace("-", " ").replace(",", " ").replace("/", " ").split(' ');
words = $.grep(words, function(n, i){
  return (n !== "" && n != null);
});
var array = words;
var newArray = array.filter(function(v){return v!==''});
console.log(newArray);
```

> ["undefined1983", "(on", "television)", "1984", "(in", "theatres)"]

I shouldn't have `undefined1983` but `1983`

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jikupin/pz3ce0o6/1178/)

Also if I do:

```
var d;
var spacetime = [];
spacetime.push({
  Title : [],
  Space : [],
  Time : {
    days : [],
    months : [],
    years : [],
    suffixes : []
  },
  articleIdPush : [],
  originalFullDate : [],
  curArtLangPrefix : ["en"],
  SingleTranslatedArticle : [],
});
var dateText = $("p").text().split(/\s+/g);
for(var i = 0; i < dateText.length; i++) {
  d += dateText[i] + ' ';
}
var words = d.replace("–", " ").replace("-", " ").replace(",", " ").replace("/", " ").split(' ');
words = $.grep(words, function(n, i){
  return (n !== "" && n != null);
});
var array = words;
var newArray = array.filter(function(v){return v!==''});
for (const word of newArray) {
  if (months.has(word)) {
    spacetime[counter].Time.months.push(word);
  } else if (+word < 32) {
    spacetime[counter].Time.days.push(+word);
  } else if (+word < 2200) {
    spacetime[counter].Time.years.push(+word);
  } else if (/\w+/.test(word)) {
    spacetime[counter].Time.suffixes.push(word);
  }
}
console.log(spacetime);
```

I get

> (index):90 Uncaught ReferenceError: months is not defined

I should have the defined array with the correct objects in it.

[jsFiddle 2](https://jsfiddle.net/jikupin/pz3ce0o6/1180/)

Comment: What is the output you are expecting?

Comment: I dont understand what is the problem? Do u want to get rid of the `undefined`? Do you want to know why is it there?

Comment: @N.Ivanov sorry just updated as I was including the second issue but the situation is similar

Comment: @abagshaw updated

Comment: If you click the `<>` button you can add code HERE instead of creating fiddles.

Comment: `var d = '';` for solving `undefined` issue.

Comment: `if (months.has(word)) {` - months are indeed not defined - you need a map

Comment: @mplungjan oh damn, you are correct. I had defined them on sublime and completely forgotten them on the fiddle, thanks

Comment: @Anarion ah! Thanks a lot

Comment: `counter` is also not defined

Comment: @mplungjan yes i saw that too but now says years not defined, I am defining them when I declare the array tho https://jsfiddle.net/jikupin/pz3ce0o6/1192/

Comment: spacetime is an array spacetime[0]....

Comment: @rob.m you've declared your `var spacetime = [];` as array, but trying to access props like it was object, that is why you've got `Cannot read property 'years' of undefined`.

Comment: @mplungjan of coooouurseee!! God thanks man, basically I was trying to reproduce my whole code and I was forgetting I had set all of this tho

Comment: @StanislavKvitash yes indeed, thank you. See previous comment

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/tgjj8koh/

Comment: @mplungjan yes exactly, works now, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with:

```
var d;
```

For the first iteration of your loop where you concatenate `d` onto itself with `d +=`, `d` is undefined. When I specified `var d = '';` it works as expected.

[Here's the working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pz3ce0o6/1182/).